# Meaning of 目当てなくせに

Tags: grammar

I'm playing a game and someone said:

```
あらぁ！　そう言ってホントは色男のカラダ目当てなくせに～！
```

My confusion comes in with `目当てなくせに`. I understand that `くせに` means `even though, despite, although, etc` and I understand that `目当て` means `aim, goal, etc` and is only a noun according to [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%AE%E5%BD%93%E3%81%A6). **But** based on the grammar rules for `くせに` I see that the `の` particle should be used with nouns, so I expect `目当てのくせに` and that doesn't seem to be the case.

So can `目当て` be used like an な-adjective or am I missing something and skewing the meaning of the sentence?

How I read it in English:

```
Well! That's sort of the truth, although the goal is for sexy male bodies.
```

Just for context, 3 people are explaining a side business where they help people become "new and better versions" of themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

色男のカラダ目当て**の**くせに also makes perfect sense. 目当て as a suffix works both as a no-adjective and a na-adjetive. For example お金目当ての犯罪 and お金目当てな犯罪 refer to the same thing, although the former sounds more formal. The same can be said with some similar suffixes like 運動嫌い(な/の), ゴミだらけ(な/の).

And くせに takes not only nouns but any other predicates (eg 強いくせに, 寝ていたくせに, etc), including na-adjectives (eg 簡単なくせに).

This sentence is saying the other speaker is hiding the true objective. It's like this:

> そう言ってホントは色男のカラダ目当てなくせに～！
> You're saying so, but {I know / the truth is} you're interested in sexy male bodies!